# PHP variables inside Xenforo template

Tags: php

I'm trying to include a PHP file in XenForo template , I think my params are wrong but anyway , it just doesn't output if I put {$varhere}. Can anyone help? My code:
Class:
http://codepad.org/BaImQd1O
Listener:
http://codepad.org/KrNxaN4z
My question is , what params I need to make it work in the template I need?

Comment: This would be a lot more helpful to others if you would include the code in your question, instead of linking off-site.

Answer (score 0):

Try after you set the new params variable to set it to the template. So...

```
$params = $template->getParams();
$params += $hookParams;
// Set in the template
$template->setParams($params);
```